# How many $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3_{>0}$ satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=n$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quantum-mechanics

How many ordered triples of positive integers $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3_{>0}$ satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2 = n$ for a given positive integer n?

This question is purely number-theoretic but originates from looking for the number of degeneracy in infinite cubical well given a certain energy level in quantum mechanics.

There are discussions in physics and chemistry communities as in [Degeneracy for different energy states in Infinite cubic well](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/degeneracy-for-different-energy-states-in-infinite-cubic-well.656253/), and [A Particle in a Three-Dimensional Box](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/03._The_Schrodinger_Equation_and_a_Particle_In_a_Box/3.9%3A_A_Particle_in_a_Three-Dimensional_Box). But the physicists and chemists didn't seem to solve the problem. I am here asking a favor from the math community to show your **number theory** skills.

Comment: For starters; if $$ is divisible by $4$, then $$, $$ and $$ must all be even, and we can divide these factors out. So it suffices to consider $$ not divisible by $4$. And reducing mod $8$, it is not hard to see that there are no solutions if $\equiv7\pmod{8}$. The classical [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) seems relevant; the Wikipedia page suggests that Gauss solved exactly this problem, but I cannot find a reference.

Comment: @abiessu I just realized and edited this out :)

Comment: The Wikipedia page seems to reference articles 291 and 292 on pages 486-495 of [Disquisitiones Arithmetica](https://archive.org/details/disquisitionesa00gaus/page/486). My Latin is a bit rusty, I cannot be bothered to go through it at the moment.

Comment: Related: http://oeis.org/A005875 , section 6 of https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227149020_On_Dirichlet_Series_for_Sums_of_Squares

Comment: @Servaes see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer/22655#22655 also other good answers there, references